# Is "tactically" an appropriate word to use in reference to animals?

Tags: expressions, synonyms

I have issue with this sentence:

> According to the habitat selection theory, individuals are assumed to behave **ideally**, thus, they are selecting available area where they achieve the highest fitness.

Is *ideally* really the best word? Would it be correct to replace it with *tactically*? Or is *tactically* appropriate only in relation to humans? I've looked for synonyms, but none of them seem to fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you're looking for is **Optimally**.

*Tactical* implies conscious planning, making a planned choice - not forced or on a whim, but following a conscious logical process. That doesn't mean the thought process was flawless or correct, it only means it wasn't haphazard or random: a decision was made with due diligence. Also, you'll rarely find this in use outside of military. "Tactically leaving a business meeting" is a bit tongue-in-cheek, often sarcastically implying "escaping cowardly".

So, no, animals don't behave tactically.

Then, "optimal" is a common, solid scientific expression meaning "best in given circumstances, according to given metric". In this case given the set of habitats and the metric of fitness, choosing the area of highest fitness is *optimal*.

Comment: and "optimally" is not synonym for "ideally"...right?

Comment: @LadislavNado: They are synonyms but not identical. "Ideally" usually implies desires, subjective feelings. "Optimally" is attached to metrics. "Ideal" is not always possible, while "optimal solution" is not always satisfactory. "Ideally" two fighting sides should stop fighting and announce peace. Optimally though, silent assassination of leaders of side A will reduce fight to minimum. (or, in your case, ideally every animal occupies a habitat that matches its adaptations perfectly. Of course there are not enough habitats to satisfy this ideal, so optimal solution must be found instead.)